# Отправить сообщение в Discord, а потом продолжить работу

Tags: python, discord

Мне нужно, что бы бот в на каком то элементе цикла отправлял сообщение, а потом шёл дальше по циклу

```
import discord
token = 'OT123123123c'
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel= client.get_channel('id')
    await channel.send('')
    await client.close()
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    if i==5:
        client.run(token)
```

но он выдаёт ошибку

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Запустите бота один раз, а цикл сделайте в `on_ready`, подойдёт?

Comment: я его и запускаю один раз. on_ready срабатывает при подключении бота. программа не идёт дальше сообщения. если вызвать on_reday  в цикле, то выдаёт RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_ready' was never awaited

Comment: Потому что бота в скрипте можно запустить только один раз. А вы пытаетесь сделать несколько. Я вам предлагаю запустить его один раз и делать все, что нужно внутри on ready

Comment: Понял вас, должно помочь, спасибо

Comment: Если что, пишите, напишу пример в ответе.

Comment: теперь он не выполняет даже начало функции on_ready. RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.  без потока, программа не будет работать, так как в ней интерфейс pyqt5

Comment: Попробуйте запустить в отдельном потоке так: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2497